# My fragment shader in WebGL program is setting all the colors from my texture to black

Tags: animation, webgl, shader, textures

I have a simple game that uses three textures with transparent parts. I can see the silhouettes of my textures, but anywhere that doesn't alpha set to zero returns black (0, 0, 0, 1).

Here's my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image0;
uniform sampler2D u_image1;
uniform sampler2D u_image2;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
// Look up a color from the texture.
vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_image0, v_texCoord);
    if (textureColor.a < 0.5) 
        discard;
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb, textureColor.a);

vec4 textureColor1 = texture2D(u_image1, v_texCoord);
    if (textureColor1.a < 0.5) 
        discard;
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor1.rgb, textureColor1.a);

vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(u_image2, v_texCoord);
    if (textureColor2.a < 0.5) 
        discard;
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor2.rgb, textureColor2.a);
```

I got the conditional that tests for alpha from another question, where pixels with zero alpha were being set to white. Solved my problem, but not sure if it scales properly to multiple textures. I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I need to add more code (vertex shader, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you actually try to achieve.
The way you wrote this code makes me think that you do not know what the `discard` statement actually does: it completely discards the fragment, the current invocation of the shader will be aborted immediately.

What you shader does is just discard the whole fragment if *any* of the 3 textures has an alpha value below 0.5. The fact that you have written to `gl_FragCoord` before doing the discard does not matter at all. If all of the textures have the  some alpha above 0.5, the final color will be that of `u_image2`.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. This explains a lot. I'm trying to only look at alpha for the current active texture. It was working properly with two textures, then broke when I added a third. Is there a way to get a reference to the active texture inside the shader? 

This code is for a game that iterates over a bunch of objects and draws them to the screen in an event loop, if that helps. I've been all over the web, looking for a tutorial that explains how to do this and have come up empty handed. If you could point me in the direction of relevant reference material, that'd be great.

Comment: @BrianABlackwell: What do you even mean by "active texture"? Every texture which is currently bound to any of the texture units could be considered active in the sense that they could be accessed by the shader (so there can be many).

Comment: Here's an example of my code:

`code`
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + this.textureIndex);

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, types[this.type].texture);


        gl.uniform1i(types[this.type].u_imageLocation, types[this.type].textureIndex); 

        // draw
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
`code`

I got this from a tutorial: Bind a null object to "clear" the currently bound texture. So I thought only one could be bound at a time.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I can't seem to get this formatted properly. Basically, I'm using gl.activeTexture(). I thought only one texture could be bound at a time and it was set to "active" with activeTexure(). I'm clearly pretty confused, but thanks for your prompt responses.

Comment: @BrianABlackwell: The GL uses a number of "texture units". Each of such a unit can have a texture bound at the time. You select the currenently "active" texture unit via `glActiveTexture`. "Active" here just means what texture unit all of the texture functions (like `glBindTexture`, `glTexImage`, `glTexParameter` etc.) will refer to.